# Ver 2.8 Texture paint works only on a few faces

Tags: uv, texture-painting

I ran into a problem today while texture painting a mesh. Did it multiple times before and everything went fine but not with this mesh.

Here my steps:

1. Made my mesh composed of few objects (nothing with weird shapes, just cubes)
2. Went in Edit Mode, selected all vertices, pressed "U" and selected "Smart UV Project"
3. Created an image for the UV map
4. Created a material with an image texture linked to the UV map Image.
5. Went into Texture paint mode and start painting on my mesh with paint mask activated so i can paint everything or just the faces i want.

Some faces got half painted vertically, horizontally or just a few parts of the face, some not getting any painting while some are good.

Don't know what I did wrong. Please help me!

[Blend file link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1WxTwknOfxChRS-V55dJ7rU9DwG35EL2K/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem probably comes from flipped normals, so select all in *Edit* mode and press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>N</kbd>, now it seems to work:

[image]

Comment: Wow! That fix my problem! Thank you so much!